# How to transform the points assigned to a rigid body along side the body?

Tags: c++, transformation, rigid-bodies

To describe the problem, I bring an example here in figure below.

As can be seen, there is a line AB and its assigned point p1. 
For this line I have a corresponding line, namely CD. I am looking for the coordinate of point p2. The relation between point p2 and line CD should be same as relation between point p1 and line AB (same distance d and same length m). I have the coordinate of points A, B, p1, C, D, and I am looking for p2. Generaly, d and m can accept a scale factor for line CD and point p2, which we know that already.

As you might know, the problem has another fake solution like p3 in the left side of line CD, which we should avoid that.

In my real problem I have 10 lines AB and around 500 point like p1 asigned to different lines AB. I have the ten corresponding lines CD, I am looking for the 500 cooresponding point p2.

Using the algebra and geometry it is possible to solve the problem, but I am looking for a fast and efficient method for implementation in C++.

Thanks very much for your comments and suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Have you made any attempt at solving this homework yourself?

Comment: This is not a homework, dear @PaulEvans. It is part of a big problem. As I mentioned, there is some algebraic and geometrical solution definitely, but I am looking for a trick to make it fast as much as possible.

Comment: This seems like a math problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to represent any movement of AB as a rotation and translation about a single point, like point A for simplicity. Then, for any other point that needs to be rotated along with AB, you should move that point into the space of line AB by subtracting point A, and then transform it back into worldspace by adding the new point A back to it after the translation and rotation.

I dont have the formula on hand atm, but Ill try to dig up an example.

**EDIT**
Untested code:

```
void transform_points(const point2f &center, vector<point2f> &points, const point2f &offset, float angle)
{
    // transform points into a space where 'center' is the origin
    mat3f to_origin = mat3f(1, 0, -center.x,
                            0, 1, -center.y,
                            0, 0, 1);

    // rotate the points around the origin
    mat3f rot = mat3f(cos(angle), -sin(angle), 0,
                      sin(angle),  cos(angle), 0,
                      0, 0, 1);

    // move the points back into world space
    mat3f to_world = mat3f(1, 0, center.x,
                           0, 1, center.y,
                           0, 0, 1);

    // offset the points by 'offset'
    mat3f off = mat3f(1, 0, offset.x,
                      0, 1, offset.y,
                      0, 0, 1);

    // concatenate all transformations for efficiency
    mat3f xform = off * to_world * rot * to_origin;

    // this loop could be parallelized using SIMD or multiple cores
    for(auto &p : points)
        p = xform * p;
}
```